# How to create a new column to a pandas dataframe that was created after using apply()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

After I read a excel file:

import pandas as pd

In:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
df = df.drop('Unnamed: 0', 1)
df
```

Out:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0   2345    typeA   NO  http://www.example.com/...
2   23423   483     NO  http://www.example.com/...
3   234234  typeC   NO  http://www.example.com/...
4   2343    typeA   NO  http://www.example.com/...
5   23423   typeA   NO  http://www.example.com/...
6   234     typeA   NO  http://www.example.com/...
```

I am applying several functions to several pandas dataframe columns that where created after adding more columns with `apply()`:

In:

```
df['E'] = df['D'].apply(checker)
df
```

Out:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0   2345    typeA   NO  http://www.example.com/...  OK
1   234     483     NO  http://www.example.com/...  FALSE
2   23423   483     NO  http://www.example.com/...  OK
3   234234  typeC   NO  http://www.example.com/...  OK
4   2343    typeA   NO  http://www.example.com/...  OK
5   23423   typeA   NO  http://www.example.com/...  FALSE
6   234     typeA   NO  http://www.example.com/...  OK
```

Then I did: `df = df[df.E == 'OK']` and `df = df.loc[df.E =='OK']`

Then, I am applying to the above dataframe a new function:

In:

```
df['F'] = df['D'].apply(new_function_foo)
```

Although it actually works as I want I got this warning:

Out:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:10: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

I checked the documentation, and I tried to follow up the instructions:

```
df['F'] = df.loc[['E']].apply(function_foo)
```

And

```
df['ColF'] = df.loc[:,'ColE'].apply(function_foo)
```

However, I do not understand how to solve the above warning. Therefore, how can I apply functions correctly?.

Comment: this is not where the warning come from. you probably created a copy of df somewhere in your code prior to that. Look for something like df2 = df prior to that line or something similar

Comment: @StevenG, I forgot to mention that: I did `df = df[df.E == 'OK']`

Comment: do this first instead: `df = df.loc[df.E =='OK']`

Comment: Thanks @StevenG. However, I got the same issue... what can I do?.

Comment: why does your name switch to A B C D E to colE colF... etc?

Comment: I was trying to be more cleare @StevenG, I updated... sorry

Comment: I added a bounty @StevenG, if you are interested.

Comment: its a warning. no big deal if the outcome you get is exactly what you want. is that the case?

Comment: You'd better post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any method you like if you are okay with copying the dataframe. For example if you do this:

```
df = df[df.E == 'OK'].copy()
```

there will be no error when you do something like this:

```
df['F'] = df['D'].apply(new_function_foo)
```

Comment: This one helped me. What are the drawbacks of using `.copy()`?

Comment: The drawback is that you use more memory because the filtered data is being copied to a new memory location

Answer (score 2):

> Then I did: df = df[df.E == 'OK'] and df = df.loc[df.E =='OK']

This is not doing what you think it is.  Reassigning `df` to a slice or view of `df` doesn't make it not a slice or view of `df`, it just makes it so you can't refer to the original `df` anymore.  Don't do this.

Then, when you try to set that slice to something, pandas warns you that setting a slice to another slice can cause unexpected results (I think this is because the method that pandas uses to do this is based on the flavor of your python implementation, but I'm not a dev).

In any case, I think what you want to do is (in the future please always show expected output):

```
df.loc[df['E']=='OK','F'] = df[df['E']=='OK']['D'].apply(function_foo)
```

or

```
df.loc[df['E']=='OK','F'] = df.loc[df['E']=='OK','D'].apply(function_foo)
```

The important part to clear the error is the `.loc` is *before* the equals sign.  This is telling pandas exactly where to put those values in the full dataframe, so nothing gets confused.  You may need to make column 'F' first, using `df.insert(5,'F',None)` so that there is something there to point to.

Answer (score 1):

I still think you did something else you are not showing us in your code. try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1, 10), 'B': range(1, 10), 'C': range(1, 10), 'D': range(1, 10), 'E': [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4]})
df = df.loc[df.E == 1]
df['F'] = df.apply(sum, axis=1)
In[71]: df
Out[71]: 
   A  B  C  D  E   F
0  1  1  1  1  1   5
1  2  2  2  2  1   9
2  3  3  3  3  1  13
```

there is no warning generated by this code.

even doing this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1, 10), 'B': range(1, 10), 'C': range(1, 10), 'D': range(1, 10), 'E': [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4]})
df = df[df.E == 1]
df['F'] = df['D'].apply(lambda x: x/2)
df
Out[77]: 
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  1  1  1  1  0
1  2  2  2  2  1  1
2  3  3  3  3  1  1
```

still no warning generated. can you create a short, replicable example of what you are getting?